# input()に入力した関数()を実行したい。

Tags: python

**やりたいこと**
input()で関数名を入力し、指定した関数を実行したいと考えています。

```
print('実行する関数を選んでください')
input()
def main():
    print('a')
    
def main2():
    print('b')
```

main()を入力して a　を出力したいと考えています。

**実行結果**

```
実行する関数を選んでください
 main()
```

そのほかにもif で分岐したりなど工夫してみましたがうまくいきません。

もしわかる方は教えていただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input()`の戻り値は文字列なので、辞書やif文を使用して分岐するよう工夫してみてください。

```
def main():
    print('a')
    
def main2():
    print('b')

print('実行する関数を選んでください')
value = input()

# if
if value == "main":
    main()
elif value == "main2":
    main2()

# 辞書による高階関数
dic = { "main": main, "main2": main2}
if value in dic.keys():
    dic[value]()

# evalで直接実行(非推奨)
eval(f"{value}()")

"""
実行する関数を選んでください
main2
b
b
b
"""
```

FYI: [eval関数をwebフォームなどで使うとなぜ危険なのか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/61989/9820)